# Why does the async request remain in the pending state in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, http, asynchronous, request

I am trying to send a message using the telegram api, but I don't want to wait for the response and the user must be redirected to another page. That's why I used `async()`. But using `async()`, the request is not sent and remains in the pending state.
While if I don't use `async()`, the request will be sent

```
function sendTelegramMessage($message)
{
    $telegram_bot_id = config('services.telegram.bot_id');
    $telegram_chat_id = config('services.telegram.chat_id');
    $promise = Http::async()->get("https://api.telegram.org/$telegram_bot_id/sendMessage?chat_id=$telegram_chat_id&text=$message&parse_mode=html");
    sleep(10);
    dd($promise->getState());
}
```

and output is:

```
"pending"
```

Edit:
I also tested the following code and the result was as follows:

```
$promise = Http::async()->get("https://api.telegram.org/$telegram_bot_id/sendMessage?chat_id=$telegram_chat_id&text=$message&parse_mode=html")->then(function ($response) {
    echo "Response received!";
    echo $response->body();
});
$a= $promise->getState();
sleep(6);
$b= $promise->getState();
dd($a,$b);
```

output:

```
"pending"
"pending"
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You're not awaiting the response and so that's why the state is `pending`.

```
$promise = Http::async()->get('http://localhost')->then(function ($response) {
    echo "Response received!";
    echo $response->body();
});

echo "The request has been sent, but we didn't wait for the response.";
```

The code above is referenced from here https://medium.com/@antoine.lame/laravel-asynchronous-and-concurrent-http-requests-9c8e3e6d36bd

Fireship.io also has a great video explanation on this here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4

Comment: The above example is waiting for 6 seconds. This does not explain why the request is still pending.